# Connecting MPU6050 with Arduino via bluetooth

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project, where I need to send data from MPU6050 accelerometer- gyroscope sensor module to an Arduino Mega board for further processing over wireless network. Bluetooth seems to be appropriate wireless network for the application. Can someone suggest how to transfer I2C data from the sensor to the arduino over bluetooth network?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to get something like the [Adafruit Bluefruit LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1697). It's a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE 4.0) nRF8001 breakout board. It simulates a UART device and sends ASCII between a device and your Arduino. Adafruit also has [sample sketches](https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout) you can adapt for your project.

Comment: This answer won't work as often the bluetooth used with MPU6050 is not a Bluetooth LE but standard Bluetooth...

Comment: What are you using on the Mega to receive the Bluetooth?

Comment: I would advise a bluetooth extension or a bluduino (beware: not a bleduino)